# what does (<typeof className>this.constructor) mean in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

when I see sourceCode of jQTree(https://github.com/mbraak/jqTree) , which is write in Typescript; I saw this:

```js
export default class SimpleWidget{
    protected static defaults = {};
    public options:any
    protected $el : JQuery

    constructor(el:Element,options:any){
        this.$el = $(el);
        console.log(typeof SimpleWidget)
        let defaults = (<typeof SimpleWidget>this.constructor).defaults;
        console.log(defaults)
        this.options = $.extend({},defaults,options);
    }
}
```

what does (this.constructor) mean? How can It get the static after Assertion?

Answer (score 1):

This class will compile to a constructor function, with the static property attached directly to it:

```
function SimpleWidget(el, options) { ... }

SimpleWidget.defaults = {};
```

Child classes would define their own `defaults`:

```
class DerivedWidget extends SimpleWidget {
  protected static defaults = { prop: 'derived default' };
}
```

which would compile to:

```
DerivedWidget.defaults = { prop: 'derived default' };
```

So the parent will want to access the child's static defaults, which it wouldn't get it if accessed `SimpleWidget.defaults`. But it can access `this.constructor.defaults`, which is dynamic.

Comment: thank you a lot. And another question is , what dost <typeof SimpleWidget> mean ?  In my mind,  " typeof SimpleWidget "  just equals string "object";but when I write <"object">this.constructor, it doesn't work.

Comment: I believe this is just done to get strong typing when accessing the static defaults property. You couldn't do `(<SimpleWidget>this.constructor).defaults` because that would mean you're casting the constructor function to an *instance* of SimpleWidget. You're actually trying to cast it to the class itself (remember - the class compiles down to a constructor function), which is done with `(<typeof SimpleWidget>this.constructor).defaults`. This is compiled out of the resulting JavaScript - you are left with just `var defaults = this.constructor.defaults`. Try it out on typescriptlang.org/play.